# API key restricted to specific Android app can be used to call maps API with no restriction

Tags: google-maps

I have API key with following configuration:

1. Application restrictions -> Android apps (with specific package name and certificate fingerprint)
2. API restrictions -> No restriction

With described configuration, it is possible to successfully call certain maps services with any client (i.e. with no regards to application restriction). For example:

- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=41.403609,2.174448&size=456x456&key=YOUR_API_KEY
- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714%2c%20-73.998&zoom=12&size=400x400&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Requests to others maps services are denied as expected. For example:

- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034&key=YOUR_API_KEY
- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Do you know of any reason for such inconsistent behavior?

Answer (score -1):

While it is true that setting restrictions to your API key will only allow it to be used by the restriction you had set, however it is an expected behavior for only the Maps Static API and Maps Streetview Static API requests to work even if there are application restrictions applied in an API key due to their particular qualities which made them different from the other APIs. These working requests would be considered as unsigned requests.

However, you can still keep your API key protected by:

- Have a dedicated API key to be used only with your Maps Static API requests and sign all your requests with digital signatures (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key#gen-sig);
- Once you have your Static Maps API requests working with a digital signature, you can lower your unsigned requests usage. To lower or disable this unsigned request use you can set "Unsigned requests (if URL signing secret is defined) per day" limit to `0` so that requests without a digital signature will not be permitted.
  https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage#view_and_edit_all_quotas_for_apis_in_a_project

Furthermore, there is an existing Feature Request in the Public Issue Tracker to break referrerless unsigned requests: https://issuetracker.google.com/124860491 You can star the issue if you are interested.

Comment: Hi @Beth. Thank you for your reply and reference to the issue in IssueTracker. Could you please elaborate more on "however it is an expected behavior for only the Maps Static API and Maps Streetview Static API requests to work even if there are application restrictions applied in an API key" (any reference to official documentation or any other source)? I would say that the issue itself and the fact that it was "verified and logged internally" by Google indicates that it is not expected behavior.

Comment: Hello @gar_r! As for "however it is an expected behavior for only the Maps Static API and Maps Streetview Static API requests to work even if there are application restrictions applied in an API key", there are no current public documentations that for this issue; "verified and logged internally" -> yes, this is not an expected behavior, and the issue was raised internally to resolve the issue.

Comment: Ok then. To accept your answer, could you please modify it so it would be clear that described behavior is not expected - in contrary it is reported and accepted issue?